# ReactJS with Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, adsense

I have a project developed with ReactJS up and running and I would like to monetize my webpage. First and best solution I found is Google AdSense. The thing is that they require certain amount of content which I believe my webpage has. My question is, will Google see that content? Of course it is not content in HTML files but JS files. Also I'm using React Router.

Do I need to do any extra steps for my webpage to get approved by Google?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://rubygarage.org/blog/seo-for-react-websites
Hope it can help.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely have a look at it.